# Why is the beracha on meat 'only' שהכל?

Tags: blessing, food, meat, shehakol-beracha

The order of berachot before eating foods are as follows ([Mishna Berurah 211:35](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=230&hilite=)): HaMotzei, Mezonot, Hagafen, HaEtz, HaAdama, and Shehakol.

I seems as though the more חשוב the food is, the greater precedence it has and the more significant the after-beracha is.

Meat is considered a delicacy, a facilitator of (non-subjective) simcha (according to the Rambam, see [here](http://www.yutorah.org/_shiurim/Simchat%20Yom%20Tov.html)), is used in important korbanot, has many halachot regarding its preparation, has a higher level of 'soul' in comparison to inanimate vegetables (Ramchal), etc.

Quote from the Rambam ([Hilchot Yom Tov 6:18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3406.htm)), talking about simchat Yom Tov:

> והאנשים, אוכלין בשר ושותין יין, שאין שמחה אלא בבשר, ואין שמחה אלא ביין.

Why then does meat not have a greater significance in terms of berachot?

Comment: Since at creation animals were not intended to be eaten we have to make a bracha about how Hashem creates everything,but we cannot call it it a food item intrinsically.

Comment: @sam Interesting. Do you have a source, or is this your own _chiddush_?

Comment: sam is qouting the gemara (or possibly rav kook who promulgated this idea)

Comment: Its a thought I have heard before,not my chiddush

Comment: https://www.etzion.org.il/en/halakha/orach-chaim/prayer-and-blessings/birkat-she-hakol  He says Sam’s idea in middle and another suggestion in the last paragraph

Answer (score 3):

1) The fact that meat comes at the cost of killing an animal, we don't make a special Beracha. Similar to why we don't say Shehecheyanu by a Bris Milah because the child is in pain.

2) The animal itself gets its nourishment from vegetation, so in that sense it can't get a greater Beracha than its life source.

Comment: Very interesting. Do you have any sources for what you are suggesting?

Comment: plants get nourishment from the earth, yet plants have a greater bracha than earth (salt)

Comment: You could argue the opposite for point 1. That one Should say a more significant beracha to fulfil several obligations, which overrides the 'cost of killing'. Is this a term borrowed from somewhere?

Answer (score -2):

True, it's puzzling at first glance but here's your answer:

[ליקוטי הלכות/אורח חיים/הלכות בציעת הפת/הלכה ב – ויקיטקסט](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%98%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%AA/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%91)

> ... ועתה נכון מאד מה שמצינו כמה ברכות פרטיות ומבררות והם חשובות יותר
> מברכות כלליות כמבאר בשלחן ערוך . ולכאורה הדבר תמוה. מה חלוק יש אם אנו
> מברכין אותו בכלל או בפרט? אך על פי הנ"ל הדבר מבאר היטב, כי כל מה
> שמברכין אותו יתברך על דבר פרטי יותר נתגלה יותר אחדות הפשוט מפעלות
> משתנות ביותר. וכל מה שהפעלות משתנות ופרטיות ביותר יקר וחשוב יותר
> כשנתגלה גם מהם אחדות הפשוט יתברך. נמצא, שכל מה שמברכין על כל דבר פרטי
> ומיחד יותר נתגלה ביותר אחדות הפשוט יתברך, כי נתגלה אחדותו יתברך מפעלות
> משתנות בפרטיות, כי עקר חשיבות התגלות אחדות הפשוט יתברך הוא דיקא
> כשנתגלה מפעלות משתנות כנ"ל. ועל כן כל מה שהפעלות משתנות ופרטיות ביותר
> יקר וחשוב יותר כשנתגלה גם מהם אחדותו יתברך ונמצא כשמברכין בכלל שהכל
> נהיה בדברו אין הברכה חשובה כל כך כמו הברכה שמברכין על דבר פרטי כגון
> בורא פרי הגפן. כי על ידי ברכת שהכל אין נתגלה כל כך בפרוש בחינת אחדות
> הפשוט יתברך מפעלות משתנות. מאחר שמברכין על כל הבריאה בכלל. אבל
> כשמברכין על דבר פרטי נתגלה מפעלות משתנות ופרטיות אחדותו יתברך. ועל כן
> ברכת שהכל היא קטנה במעלה מברכות פרטיות כמו שכתוב בשלחן ערוך וכן כיוצא
> בזה. ועקר החשיבות של כל הדברים הוא על ידי הדעת, כי החכמה מחיה הכל.
> ובכל מקום שמלבש הדעת ביותר הוא חשוב יותר ומברכין עליו ברכה חשובה
> ביותר, דהינו ברכה פרטיות. כי מחמת חשיבותו קובע ברכה לעצמו כמו שאמרו
> רבותינו זכרונם לברכה על כמה דברים , הינו מחמת שמלבש בו דעת ביותר.
> והדעת הוא העולם הבא. כי זה עקר העולם הבא, דהינו לדעת אותו יתברך להודות
> ולברך אותו יתברך כנ"ל. ועל כן בכל מה שיש בו בחינת דעת יותר הוא נכלל
> ביותר בהעולם הבא. ויכולין לברך עליו ברכה חשובה ביותר, דהינו ברכה
> פרטיות, דהינו לכלל אותו הפעלה בפרט בתוך העולם הבא שיהיה נכלל באחדותו
> יתברך וכנ"ל. כי הכל תלוי בדעת שכל מה שהדעת יותר גדול משיגין ביותר
> אחדות הפשוט יתברך ונכללין ביותר פעלות משתנות ופרטיות באחדות הפשוט
> יתברך:
>
> ...
> **And now it is very clear to us that there are many specific and explicit blessings (fruit, bread etc.) that are more important than general blessings (shehakol),
> as explained in the Shulchan Aruch. At first glance, it is puzzling.
> What difference does it make if we bless it in general or in detail?**
> But according to the above, it is well explained, because everything
> that we bless specifically about is more revealed within the simple
> Unity of constantly changing operations. And everything that involves
> altered and specific activities is more valuable and important when
> His simple Unity is also revealed. Therefore, everything that is
> blessed on every specific and individual thing is more revealed within
> the simple Unity of constantly changing operations, for His simple
> Unity is revealed through individual and specific activities. And
> hence, everything that involves altered and specific actions is more
> valuable and important when His simple Unity is also revealed. Thus,
> when we bless in general, such as "**everything happens by His
> word**," the blessing is not as important as the blessing we make on
> specific things, such as "Creator of the fruit of the vine." **For
> through the blessing of Shehakol, His simple Unity of constantly
> changing operations is not very apparent, since we bless Shehakol
> Nihyah Bidvaro**, but when we bless something specific, His constantly
> changing and specific activities are revealed, and His simple Unity so
> gets blessed. **This be the reason why the blessing of Shehakol is
> less significant than specific blessings, as written in the Shulchan
> Aruch and so forth.** The key to all these things is Daat, knowledge,
> for (Prov. X.x) "wisdom enliveneth all things." And wherever knowledge
> is present, it is more important, and a blessed blessing, that is, a
> specific blessing, is determined for it. As our sages, may their
> memory be blessed, said about many things, it is because knowledge is
> present in it more. And knowledge is the world to come. For this is
> the essence of the world to come, that is, to know Him and bless Him
> as well. Therefore whatever gots loftier Daat, is mo' included in the
> world to come. And we can bless it with the most important blessing,
> that is, a specific blessing, which includes its operation
> specifically within the world to come, which will be encorporated in
> His simple Unity. For everything depends on knowledge, and everything
> that has greater knowledge attains more of the simple Unity, and is
> included in constantly changing and specific activities within the
> simple Unity.
>
> ...

Comment: As R' Nathan explains toward the end of this paragraph .. and go see the before and after .. the key to it all is Daat. You have Etz Hadaat.. compare with a dumb beast Behemah that has no Daat or Dibbur regardless of its other amazing facilities. See L. Halakhot for more .. or my favorite is say Nanach and daven for it then open the Safer .. sifrei Breslev of course

Comment: This just in from our fren Simcha H Nanach:

Comment: HH really Shehakol is the highest, because שהכל נהיה בדברו - acronym Nachman Ben Simcha. And Shehakol is gematria פצפצי"ה which is gematria Na NaCh NaChMa NaChMaN with the inclusive.
NNNNM

Comment: And one more:HH
בשר - ראשי תיבות רבינו בן שמחה.
נ נח

Comment: Thanks for the source, but it seems like you've set up the question for an answer, but didn't answer the question using the source. Please could you elaborate?